# Why IntelliJ Idea doesn't recognize the dollar operator of JQuery?

Tags: jquery, intellij-idea, dollar-sign

IntelliJ shows a warning "*Unresolved function or method $()*" when mouse over the `$` sign despite the file is in the same directory as js file. So I can't take advantage of intellisense when typing `$` functions.

Just one line of code and the IDE didn't recognize it. But it works. How can I fix this problem?

```
$(".container").get(0).appendChild(proDiv);
```

Comment: @Mifeet I don't think this is a duplicate of that question, since the question you referred was about a bug in the IDE that was already fixed a year ago.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I have found the solution by myself.

1. First press `CTRL + ALT + S` and go to settings.
2. Then click from the menu `Languages & Frameworks`
3. Select `JavaScript` from the section below and select `Libraries`
4. In the open menu on the right, click on the `Download` button and select `jquery` from the list.
5. Download it and apply. It is done.

[image: downloading a library with IntelliJ]

Comment: If you require a specific version of jQuery: Download the js file and store it somewhere meaningful. Then click `Add...` instead of the fourth step, specify name and framework type, and attach the js file.

Comment: You may need to restart the application.

Comment: If adding the file yourself (e.g. if you require a specific version) you will need to import the _unminified_ version of the file.

Answer (score 0):

a solution is just to type `npm install jquery` in ur Rider Terminal and it will get installed by itself. I hope this was usefull.

kind regards

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).